# How to add multiple variables in text using python

Tags: python

I am very new to coding and I wanted to try and create a MadLib using Python. I've already created the inputs, but I can't figure out how to add multiple variables into one print syntax.

`print("Suddenly he grabs me. tipping me across his", bodyPart1, adj1 "movement, he angles his", noun1 "so my", bodyPart2 "is resting on the", noun2 "beside him")`

Comment: i think you're just missing a few commas

Comment: You have the pieces; the only problem is details of language syntax.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = "is"
string2 = "some"
print("This {} a {} with {} formatting.".format(string1, "string", string2)
```

returns

"This is a string with some formatting."

Alternately:

```
print("This " + string1 + " a string with " + string2 + " formatting.")
```

I like the first one better because it lets you keep track of spaces etc more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simply use the '+' operator to concatenate strings together, like so:

INPUT:

```
x = 'How '
y = 'are'
z = ' you?'

print('Hello ' + 'there!\n' + x + y + z + '\nGreat!')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hello there!
How are you?
Great!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
print("Suddenly he grabs me. tipping me across his", bodyPart1, adj1, "movement, he angles his", noun1, "so my", bodyPart2, "is resting on the", noun2, "beside him")
```

or

```
print("Suddenly he grabs me. tipping me across his" + str(bodyPart1) + str(adj1) + "movement, he angles his" + str(noun1) + "so my" + str(bodyPart2) + "is resting on the" + str(noun2) + "beside him")
```

For case 1, you need to add comma after each "word" and variable.
2nd case is called string concatenation. I am enclosing the variables in `str()` to make sure that the variable type changes to string, thus allowing for concatenation.

Hope this helps.